# Using Mac style with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

How do I apply the Mac style on my forms and windows, using Qt?

Answer (score 6):

If I'm not mistaken, the Mac style is not available on non-Mac plaforms (i.e. windows).

See [QMacStyle details](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qmacstyle.html#details)

You'd have to create your own style reproducting the Mac style, but that is not trivial. Have a look at Qt documentation : [Implementing Styles and Style Aware Widgets](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/style-reference.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use appname -style macstyle or mac